# How to get an individual which match an Objectproperty with Jena?

Tags: jena, ontology, owl, pellet

Let consider the following ontology, where `PERSON`, `NAME`, `SURNAME` and `IDENTIFICATION` are classes. `NAME` and `SURNAME` are subclass of `IDENTIFICATION`. `hasSurname` and `hasName` are **functional ObjectProperty**. `hasValue` is a DataTypeProperty with domain `IDENTIFICATION` and Range string.

[image]

Let do an automatic instanciation of this model using jena with 2 persons, person1 is "Henry Ford" and person2 is "Harrison Ford".

To deal with this repetition a want to automatically instanciate the ontology according to the following schema, where the individual `name1` is used both for person1 and person2.

```
String   NS    = .... // the name space
OntModel model = .... // Jena model to use   

// creating all the individuals with random uri

Individual person1  = model.createIndividual(NS + "PERSON" + Math.random());
Individual name1    = model.createIndividual(NS + "NAME" + Math.random());
Individual surname1 = model.createIndividual(NS + "SURNAME" + Math.random());
Individual person2  = model.createIndividual(NS + "PERSON" + Math.random());
Individual name2    = model.createIndividual(NS + "NAME" + Math.random());
Individual surname2 = model.createIndividual(NS + "SURNAME" + Math.random());

// asserting that ...
// person1 _hasName_ (name1 _hasValue_ "Ford")     
// person1 _hasSurname (surname1 _hasValue_ "Henry")

name1.addProperty(model.getOntProperty(NS + "hasValue"), Resourcefactory.createLiteral("Ford"));
surname1.addProperty(model.getOntProperty(NS + "hasValue"), Resourcefactory.createLiteral("Henry"));
model.add(person1, model.getOntProperty(NS + "hasName"), name1);
model.add(person1, model.getOntProperty(NS + "hasSurname"), surname1);


name1 = null; // loosing reference to name1

// asserting that ...
// person2 _hasName_ name1
// person2 _hasSurname (surname2 _hasValue_ "Harrison")
```

How to find individual of class `NAME` which property `hasvalue` is "Ford" to correctly finish the instanciation ?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, why do `surname1` and `surname2` have to be distinct individuals? The use of `Math.random()` looks very odd there. If you think about your stated problem, you have two individuals, Henry Ford and Harrison Ford, and in your domain model you want the name and surname to be separate individuals (I assume you have a good reason for this, it's an odd way of approaching this particular problem). So the question I have for your modelling approach is: is there one surname Ford that is shared by both persons, or are there two surnames which happen to have the same `hasValue` literal?

Personally, I would approach this by exploiting the common structure in the graph:

```
ns:ford 
  a ns:Surname ;
  ns:hasValue "Ford".

ns:harrison
  a ns:FirstName ;
  ns:hasValue "Harrison".

ns:henry
  a ns:FirstName ;
  ns:hasValue "Henry".

ns:person1
  a ns:Person ;
  ns:firstName ns:henry ;
  ns:surname ns:ford .

ns:person2
  a ns:Person ;
  ns:firstName ns:harrison ;
  ns:surname ns:ford .
```

But, I don't know what problem you're trying to solve so I can't really say whether this is the right approach for you. It would make it easy, for example, to find all the people that have the same surname.

Generally speaking, if you *don't* want to share nodes in a graph, so you do want the two different uses of Ford to be distinct, you could use blank nodes to save messing about with random numbers:

```
ns:person1
  a ns:Person ;
  [a ns:SurName ; ns:hasValue "Ford"] ;
  [a ns:FirstName ; ns:hasValue "Henry"].
```

So my main answer to you question is to be clear about the graph you're trying to build. Then it will be a lot clearer what Jena calls you need to make.

To answer your specific question, if you want to locate a particular resource based on a pattern of its properties, I'd suggest using a SPARQL query. You can do it with a pattern of Jena API calls, but SPARQL queries are much more compact once you get past a small initial size of pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Ian_Dickinson for your reply. To answer your question I will say that I want to build a graph where the surname Ford could be shared by many persons. This is in the purpose of reducing the size of the produced owl file. The problem is how to determine if there is already a surname in my Jena model too which I could link a new person to?. So find an individual of class Surname where his property hasValue match 'ford'. If there is not I will created the new surname else I will link the new person to this surname. In your answer It look like SPARQL could help (How ?)

Comment: If you look carefully at my suggested OWL code, you'll see that there is only one node for the Ford surname with the URI `ns:ford`. In a Jena model, if you call `getResource()` it will either create a new resource in the model if there is not one there already, or re-use the same resource if there is. So you don't need to use SPARQL - as long as you use the same URI. If you use your URI's with a random number added, this obviously won't work.

Comment: In my case, I don't have the uri of the resource. This is due to the fact that this resource had been instanciated some loops ago in automatic ontology instanciation code. The only information that I have about the resource is that It has a given property value "Ford". So I'm interested among all Individual of a given class by the one which has a given property value.

Comment: In that case, use SPARQL as I suggested or `Model.listSubjectsWithProperty()` - http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#listSubjectsWithProperty(com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property)